# Viewing offline HTML5 site (not connected to network)

Tags: html, offline, html5-appcache, offlineapps, offline-browsing

My team and I have just developed an offline portion of a web application utilizing HTML5, jquery and a cache manifest. The problem I am running into is when I disconnect from a wireless network, I am not able to view my offline site ( I receive a default screen from IE saying please connect to a network )?

I know that I have coded my offline cached site correctly because the site can be viewed when I disable my network adapter, just not a network adapter is on and not connected to a network?

Does anyone know if there is a way to bypass this default screen in IE when trying to view an offline site after disconnecting from a network?

Here is an offline page that was generated from our system:https://learn.questce.com/BranchAudit/OfflineSync/149/55/Michael-Kirk201372692619.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IE9 does not support cache manifest](http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps).  IE 10+ does, but it seems if you close the browser you can't re-open the site while offline (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367467/ie-10-not-using-appcache-after-browser-closed)).

Answer (score 1):

I did not get your question very clearly. But from what i understand, i will advice you to check out the offline browsing feature of internet explorer.

If you have already tried it and it is not working properly then you can try to run it in a browser named: "BackStreet Browser 3.2".

It is a high speed downloading browser and it is capable of downloading "HTML", "Java applets", "graphics" and many more features.

You can also view more details about this browser from: http://www.spadixbd.com/backstreet/

Comment: Thank you for your response Nelson.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion of utilizing the backstreet browser, unfortunately my company works in the financial services industry and need to cater to our users being able to use IE. I aplogize if my initial question was somewhat garbled. The issue that I face is that I am not able to view any html5 offline sites while disconnected from a wireless network on IE, it just throws a default screen asking me to connect to a network. When I turn off my network adapter, I am actually able to view my offline cached page?? I am pretty clueless on whee to go from here.