# IE 10 not using AppCache after browser closed

Tags: internet-explorer-10, html5-appcache, offline-browsing

I wrote an application using the [HTML5 Cache Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and I'm having a problem using it in IE 10.

I used Fiddler to witness the manifest file being downloaded and all resources fetched on the initial load of the application.  If I disable my network adapter to force the machine offline, the application continues to work as expected as long as I don't close the browser window.

However, when I close the browser window, then attempt to re-open the page from a favorite, IE 10 tells me "You're not connected to a network".  Obviously I know that, I'm trying to use the app offline.  These exact steps work in Chrome.

Is this behavior by design?  Is there a workaround?  I can't test with IE 11 right now...is this different in IE 11?

Answer (score 1):

Hearing of some issues of the appcache clearing if your company utilizes gpo settings and has "empty temporary internet files folder when browser is closed" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the answer to this? I have the same problem. I did get a bit further though. I found that if you go to the IE10 File menu option and tick Work Offline then try and access your cached app it loads the page but I still have an issue as it does not appear to be using the javascript file that should also be cached. All works ok on Google Chrome but our clients are restricted to IE so Chrome is not an option.

Comment: When I am using IE 10 and tick the Work Offline box, it does not load the page -- it asks me if I want to go online to get the page.  No matter what I answer, it doesn't allow me to see the cached page.  I am using IE 10.0.9200.16580 on a Surface Pro.

Comment: Mine is now working, I sorted the issue with javascript, a function that was erroring while offline although worked ok on Chrome. Are you sure your pages have cached properly, I had a similar issue and it turned out not all the pages had cached. For reference my version of IE10 is 10.0.9200.16686 on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. Is your cached site available anywhere for me to try it for you?

Comment: No, sorry, it is an Intranet site on my work network.  The caching is working because the site continues to work even when I disable the wifi adapter (the only connection to the network).  I open new browser windows and can't reach any other sites.  As long as I keep that window open, it works.